# how to use name of submit button in " isset()" function whose name is dynamically given?

Tags: php

I am creating many buttons based on id of database query in  php. But I am not able to use name attribute of clicked button in PHP isset function on different php page.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo "<form method='post' action='#'>";
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["iname"]. " </td> 
               <td>" . $row["itype"]. "</td><td>".$row["icost"]."</td> 
               <td>".$row["irestaurant"]."</td><td>"; 
        ?>
        <input type="submit"  name="<?php echo $row["id"];?>" 
                 value="Order Now" onclick="btn(name)"></td></tr>
        <?php

    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";
```

Comment: You could loop over the `$_POST` variable and check for a numerical key. But wouldn't it make more sense to name the submit button something like "order_id" and set its `value` attribute to `$row["id"]`? That way, you could just check for the ID in `$_POST['order_id']`, because only the value of the submit button you actually clicked will be passed in the post data.

Answer (score 0):

The post will contain a name => value where the name will be value of `echo $row["id"];` and the value will be `Order Now`

**Note** that you are repeating creating a `<form>` tag for every iteration of the while loop and closing it only once.

For your example, one option to get the id from the submit is to use for example [array_search](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to return the first corresponding key for that value.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo "id: " . array_search('Order Now', $_POST, true);
}
```

Another option could be to give the button a name for example `submit` instead of the row id and pass the row id to a function which will add a hidden input to the form with the value of the row id.

That hidden input you can also give name for example `id` so you can get them both by using the key name from the post array.

For example:

```
function btn(id) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "id");
    input.setAttribute("value", id);
    document.forms[0].appendChild(input);
}
```

And the input

```
<input type="submit"  name="submit"
           value="Order Now" onclick="btn(<?php echo $row["id"];?>)">
```

The post array could look like:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 200
    [submit] => Order Now
)
```